# Jquery find data with :not

Tags: jquery

I am trying to filter a table with jquery. Each row in table has a data attribute which tells something about that row, I am now trying to hide all the lines that do not have that data item. I have so far:

```
function filterResource() {
    var item = $('#resources option:selected').text();
    $("#tableBody").find("[data-resource='"+ item +"']:not").each(function (key, value) {
        $(value).toggle();
    });
}
```

But it does not work. It does work without `:not`, but does the opposite to what I want to. 
I've also tried

```
$("#tableBody").not("[data-resource='" + item + "']").each(function (key, value) {
    $(value).toggle();
});
```

But it is not correct.

Row is:

```
<tr class="even" data-resource="something1" role="row">
```

How to find all elemets that **do not** contain specific data attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop over trs:

```
$("#tableBody tr").not("[data-resource='" + item + "']").each(function (key, value) {
    $(value).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

while you said each row

```
$("#tableBody tr:not([data-resource='" + item + "'])").each(function (key, value) {
    $(value).toggle();
});
```

Additional: *if needed*

```
var item = $.trim($('#resources option:selected').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution which doesn't require attribute selectors to be supported:

```
$('#tableBody tr').each(function(key, element){

    if($(element).attr('data-resource') !== item){
        //do stuff
    }

});
```